# Make div 100% height inside another DIV

Tags: html, css

I need to balance the height of a div which is next to other, I am using Bootstrap and I can not do the same size.
[Columns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pqBMh.png)
[Divs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/npVFp.png)

Comment: what's the problem of positng real code and not a screenshot?

Comment: We will need more info, can you paste the relative HTML & CSS?

Comment: you need to set body and html height : 100%; like : html, body { height:100%}

Answer (score 0):

Please try using css Flex Property:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style> 
#main {
    width: 220px;
    height: 300px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    display: -webkit-flex; /* Safari */
    display: flex;
}

#main div {
    -webkit-flex: 1;  /* Safari 6.1+ */
    -ms-flex: 1;  /* IE 10 */    
    flex: 1;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="main">
  <div style="background-color:coral;">RED</div>
  <div style="background-color:lightblue;">BLUE</div>  
  <div style="background-color:lightgreen;">Green div with more content.</div>
</div>

<p><b>Note:</b> Internet Explorer 9 and earlier versions do not support the flex property.</p>

<p><b>Note:</b> Internet Explorer 10 supports an alternative, the -ms-flex property. IE11 and newer versions fully support the flex property (do not need the -ms- prefix).</p>

<p><b>Note:</b> Safari 6.1 (and newer) supports an alternative, the -webkit-flex property.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to give the child height 100% like that it takes 100% height of his parent

```css
.parent{
  height: 150px;
  width:100px;
  background-color:pink;
}
.child{
  height:100%; 
  width:70px;
  background-color:green;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">

  </div>
</div>
```